# migrating from windows to ubuntu

Tags: vlc, steam, gpu, microsoft-office, handbrake

my primary concerns are,

**1. Dota 2 (steam game)** - Will i need to reinstall "steam client and game" once i change 
                         os from win 7 to ubuntu 14.1 ?(Ubuntu supports Steam client)

**2. MS office** - Will i need to uninstall before i change os?
               if yes, what will happen to files ?
               after changing os, will i be able to open those files in open office or
               libre office ?

**3. Handbrake & VLC**  - Will i need to reinstall them ? (both support ubuntu)

**4. GPU**              - I use Asus R7-250, will i need to reinstall drivers  ?

Comment: Handbrake does not have a build for the newest version of Ubuntu - if this is a 'must-have' then you will need Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: You will lose all programs you currently have - it is a completely new operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you installed on Windows doesn't matter to Linux (or for that matter, to another Windows installation).

1. Yes
2. No, you need not uninstall MS Office. Yes, most files should open fine in LibreOffice.
3. Yes
4. Yes

If you use Steam on Wine, you should be able to use the library you already have downloaded, but that has it's own set of problems, and for a game that does support Linux, isn't worth it.

Think of it as reinstalling Windows. How many of these questions would have the same answer?

Comment: will ubuntu installer uninstall all my previous installed apps ?

Comment: @gambler420 you can choose to install alongside Windows. That will leave Windows untouched.

Answer (score 1):

You can't take any installed programs from Windows to Ubuntu Linux. After installing Ubuntu, you have to install any program you need.

1. You have to install DotA2 and the Steam Client after installing Ubuntu. I know, downloading DotA2 takes ages...
2. There is no MS Office for any Linux Version. And I doubt ther will ever be one. However, Ubuntu comes along with a preinstalled version of *LibreOffice*, which is compatible with MS Office documents to about 95% (estimated by be...). You have to make a **backup of your files** before installing Ubuntu.
   The installation progress will **wipe your whole HDD**, as long as you don't have your files on a second partition and then partition your HDD manually.
3. If these programs are available for Ubuntu, you can install them after the Ubuntu installation.
4. The AMD driver `fglrx` for the AMD Radeon R7-250 can be installed via Ubuntu's **driver manager**.

Comment: 1. i can backup dota 2 and use it in ubuntu after reinstalling steam client ?

Comment: 2. u mean i backup files using msoffice and use libre office to open it ??(i dont mean to be silly, just confused)

Comment: 4. should i uninstall drivers b4 changing os ? will ubuntu automatically install required drivers ?

Comment: @gambler420 1. Yes, if you use Wine. 2. There is an option to install alongside Windows, that should keep your files. However, OS installation can have problems and you should always back up (copy) your documents and personal files to an external disk. 4. Ubuntu won't install drivers automatically, but should show which ones are available.

Comment: @gambler420 1. Why would you want to backup DotA? Everything's saved on Steam's servers. 2. You copy the files to an external HDD or save it in a cloud. 4. Ubuntu uses generic drivers which work with most devices. For your graphics card, install fglrx via the Driver Manager